# All possible combinations in python (with one fixed parameter)?

Tags: python

I have the next type of objet:

```py
class Filter():
    default_params= ... # i.e. (1, 5)
    all_possible_params = [(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6)]
```

And then I have a list of this objects `filters = [Filter_1(), Filter_2(),..]` in which each filter have different values for his two attributes.

So, my problem, is that I want a method that return all the possible params combinations, but in each combination I only want to iterate over `all_possible_params` of one of the filters, while the other filters keep with his `default_params`.

I think is better to understand with an example. I want to run the next code:

```py
filters_list = [Filter(), Filter(), Filter()]
res = generate_onefilter_restdefault_combinations(filters_list)
```

And have the next output in ´res´:

```py
[((1,5),(1,5),(1,5)), ((1,5),(1,5),(1,6)), ((1,5),(1,5),(2,5)), ((1,5),(1,5),(2,6)),
((1,5),(1,6),(1,5)), ((1,5),(2,5),(1,5)), ((1,5),(2,6),(1,5)),
((1,6),(1,5),(1,5)), ((2,5),(1,5),(1,5)), ((2,6),(1,5),(1,5))]
```

**Updated (best explanation):**

In that case I have 3 filters with 4 possible params each one, so if I calculate all the possble combination with `itertools.product(*[f.all_possible_params for f in filters_list])` I will get 64 combinations (4*4*4). And I'm not looking for that.

I want to set the first filter to its default paameter while it is on all possible combinations of the other two filters (`itertools.product(*[f2.allparams()+f3.allparams()]`). Then I want to set the second filter to its default parameter and iterate over all the combinations of filters 1 and 3 (`itertools.product(*[f1.allparams()+f3.allparams()]`). And finally to do the same thing again but this time fixing the filter 3. And at the end of the whole eliminate the possible duplicates.

Comment: The question with the current wording doesn't make a lot of sense. How about fleshing out a few full examples where we see all the inputs and are provided the expected outputs you're looking for. It isn't intuitive right now how you came up with this expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the `Filter` to just be a dict with properties, but given that, this is my implementation:

```py
import itertools

# dummy data
filters = [
  {
    'default': (1,5),
    'all_params': [
      (1,5),
      (1,6),
      (2,5),
      (2,6)
    ]
  }, {
    'default': (3,6),
    'all_params': [
      (4,5),
      (4,6),
      (5,5),
      (5,6)
    ]
  }, {
    'default': (6,7),
    'all_params': [
      (9,9),
      (9,8),
      (7,5),
      (7,6)
    ]
  }
]
result_set = []
    for idx,f in enumerate(filters):
    rest = filters[idx+1:]
    all_params_together = [p for r in rest for p in r['all_params']]
    for perm in itertools.permutations(all_params_together, len(filters)-1):
        result_set.append([f['default']] + list(perm))
```